# Is there a way to override __format__ method

Tags: python, string

we know that :

```
str.format('{:+>10}', 'sometext')
```

will return :

```
'++sometext'
```

or :
`'{:+>10}'.format('sometext')` will return  `'++sometext'`
my question, is there away to override **format** method of instance of a class.... i have try this:

```
class A:
    def __format__(self, spec):
        return spec.format(self)
```

then instantiate it :

```
a = A()
a.__format__('{:+>20}')
```

returning `'+>20'` how could this happen...
thanks before

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to ask or what you wanted that `__format__` method to return. `__format__` is an ordinary method that you can override like any other, and you have already done so.

Comment: yes i mean... how we can make use of it to formatting string that we desire

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `def __format__(self,spec):`, `spec` is the format string itself.  If you want to format the class using that spec, you need to specify it as a format to the content of the class instance in some way, such as:

```
class Value:

    def __init__(self,value):
        self.value = value

    def __format__(self,fmt):                # fmt='03' from below.
        return f'Value({self.value:{fmt}})'  # f'Value({self.value:03})' is evaluated.

v = Value(5)
print(f'{v:03}')         # Python 3.6+
print('{:04}'.format(v)) # Python <3.6
```

Output:

```
Value(005)
Value(0005)
```

Comment: is there a way to format direct to the "self", i try but it returns maximum recursion, i try call super but it returns not recognize / unsupported format string or maybe this is python convension that self has own standard format. i mean like +++'<__main__.Value object at 0x7fdaa11792b0>'

Answer (score 0):

You could create a class like this which takes in an initial `int` value as the length. I tested in Python 3 and this works.

```
class Padded:
    def __init__(self, length: int=10, pad='+'):
        self.value = '{{:{}>{}}}'.format(pad, length)
    def format(self, value):
        return self.value.__format__(value)

a=Padded(20)
print(a.__format__('Sometext')) 
#++++++++++++Sometext
```

Comment: You haven't demonstrated overriding `__format__` as the OP requested.  You've just provided a method named `format` to the class.

Comment: `__format__` isn't meant to be called directly.  You override it and it is called indirectly by the f-strings or `.format`.  See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Can override **format** this way (refered from python cookbook)**

```
_formats = {

  'ymd' : '{d.year}-{d.month}-{d.day}',

  'mdy' : '{d.month}-{d.day}-{d.year}' 

}

class Date:

def __init__(self,year,month,day):

    self.year = year
    self.month = month
    self.day = day

def __format__(self,code):

     fmt = _formats[code]
     return fmt.format(d=self) #passed self as instance to d (Note using this d in _formats to get the attribute)


d = Date(2021,8,23)

#format method can be called from either these 2 ways

print(d.__format__('ymd'))

print(format(d,'mdy'))

#output

2021-8-23

8-23-2021
```